# How to know the index number of all specific numbers in a list in python

Tags: python, list, indexing, append

Look at the following list of numbers:

```
dlist = [23.0, 28.6, 32.9, 34.9, 34.2, 31.0, 25.9, 20.1, 15.0, 11.8, 11.1, 13.1, 17.4, 23.0, 28.6, 32.9, 34.9, 34.2, 31.0, 25.9, 20.1, 15.0, 11.8, 11.1, 13.1, 17.4]
```

Now I try to find the index numbers of all the numbers in the list which are higher than 25. Then I want to make a list of those index numbers.

```
for i in dlist:
    if i >= 25:
        checklist.append(list_degrees.index(i))
```

Now the problem is that it registers some index numbers twice. For example: we see the first number above 25: 28.6. This number has the index number 1. If we look further, we see again 28.6, this should have the index number 14. Instead, it got the index number 1 again.

Here you see my "wrong" output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Would someone have an answer to my problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `list_degrees` isn't defined.

Comment: `L.index(elem)` returns the index of the _first_ occurrence of `elem` in `L`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like the example below:

```
dlist = [23.0, 28.6, 32.9, 34.9, 34.2, 31.0, 25.9, 20.1, 15.0, 11.8, 11.1, 13.1, 17.4, 23.0, 28.6, 32.9, 34.9, 34.2, 31.0, 25.9, 20.1, 15.0, 11.8, 11.1, 13.1, 17.4]

checklist = []
for idx, val in enumerate(dlist):
    if val >= 25:
        checklist.append(idx);

print(checklist);
```

The reason your code wasn't working correctly is because `index` returns the index of *first occurance* in that list, causing values later in the list to show up with a wrong index because they get the `index` of the item with the same value that's also appearing earlier in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
indices_greater_than_5 = [idx for idx,value in enumerate(my_values) if value > 5]
```

is one way you could do it with a simple list comprehension that uses `enumerate` to count from `0..len(my_values)-1`

Answer (score 0):

Using `index` returns the index of the first occurrence of that item in your list (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). This is why you only get the earlier appearing indexes, to gather all the indexes you would want to use `enumerate`

Use `enumerate` and only take the indexes of items with a value greater than `25`

```
res = [i for i, v in enumerate(dlist) if v > 25]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use numpy's [where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function:

```
import numpy as np

np.where(np.asarray(dlist) > 25)[0]

# array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
```